Data Mismatch When Reading MFM384 (Selec) Registers Using RS485 to USB Converter and Pymodbus (Python)
I am attempting to read input registers from MFM384 (Selec) devices using an RS485 to USB converter with Python (pymodbus).
When I read the "Running Hour" and "Total Net kWh" from the devices, the values I obtain do not match those displayed on the devices.
For example, the "Running Hour" register shows a value that is 5 hours less than what is displayed on one of the MFM384 devices. Similarly, the "Total Net kWh" value is also much lower than the device's displayed data.
In contrast, when I read from another device, the "Running Hour" is reported as 21 hours greater than the displayed value. Likewise, the "Total Net kWh" is significantly higher than the value shown on that device.
My Code Snippet:
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient

from pymodbus.client.mixin import ModbusClientMixin

# Create Modbus Serial client
client = ModbusSerialClient(
    port='/dev/tty.usbserial-1130',
    baudrate=9600,
    timeout=3,
    parity='E',
    stopbits=1,
    bytesize=8
)

# Connect to the client
if client.connect():
    # Reading running hour
    address = 30083 - 30000
    results = client.read_input_registers(address, 2, slave=255)
    print("registers", results.registers)
    value = client.convert_from_registers(registers=results.registers, data_type=ModbusClientMixin.DATATYPE.FLOAT32)
    print(f"The reading value is: {value}")
    client.close()
else:
    print("Unable to connect to the Modbus device.")

Output for Run hours Registers (Device shows 1695):
registers [17619, 10624]
The reading value is: 1689.296875

Output for Total Net kWh Registers [30059](Device shows  642720):
registers [18716, 53600]
The reading value is: 642326.0

Have I missed anything?

The manual indicates that values are Big Endian (ABCD) by default.  You don't show us sample values for combined_registers/value (or the expected result) which makes it difficult yo comment further. You might find it simpler using the conversion functions provided by pymodbus (e.g. convert_from_registers)

@Brits, Here is the sample value of the Big Endian Format:
Total Net Energy: 642326 KWH (Expected: 642720 kWh)
Run Hour: 1689 (Expected: 1694)

So the raw data used to calculate 642326 will have been 491cd160 (please check that - ideally provide your code). The raw value for 642720 would be 491cea00, note how the only difference is in the low word. I'd guess that your read is out by one register and this is hidden by endianess issues (it's easier to help if you provide more code and intermediate results).

@Brits, I’m currently away from my workstation, but I can share my pseudocode here. Could you please take a look and let me know if anything is wrong?
https://pastebin.com/5gxdqeaw

I would try replacing address = 30084 - 30001 with address = 30084 - 30000 (the addrerss table in the docs appears to be 0 based - this is often confusing with Modbus).

@Brits,
address = 30084 - 30000, the registers value: [10624, 18537], Converted value: 5.696903045875404e-14 (float32), 696273001 (int32)
||||
address = 30084 - 30001, the registers value: [17619, 10624], Converted value: 1689.296875 (float32), 1154689408 (int32).
The device shows: 1695.
Could you plz suggest me anything to get the exact value?

I can't see any match here. However just noticed that your code says "Reading running hour" whereas I assumed you wanted kWh1 (Imp) (which the Docs I found say are at "30084 / 0x54"). Please try reading registers 82 and 83 (30082 in the docs). Note your code is confusing as it says "300084 is returning the correct hour value" but that does not appear to be the case? (please clarify what reading you are checking on the screen, and edit the question with full details). Maybe use something like mbpoll to juist dump redisters 80-90?

@Brits, Question has been edited. Please have a look.

Why are you now reading reg 83? This will be simpler if you output a wider range (ideally showing the raw modbus request/response).

@Brits, Previously I was using 30084-30001 = 83. Now 30083-30000 = 83, So both are same.
